# Is it common to sort a row in a DP table to extract the solution?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, recursion, dynamic

I have two input arrays of the same length *n* containing positive integers. *n* is always an even number. Using this input I have to build a new array of length *n* containing *n/2* elements of each input array and at every index of the new array there must be an element at the same index of one of the two input arrays. The sum of all entries in the new array has to be as low as possible. In other words I have to compare the two input arrays at every index and choose them in a way to have the lowest sum possible using *n/2* entries of each array.

My approach is to create a DP table with 3 rows. Row 1 is input *array1*, row 2 is input *array2* and row 3 is the difference (array1 - array2). To extract the solution I would then sort the table in ascending order with respect to row 3.

My question is if this is (common) practice or/and if there is a better solution.

[DP table before sorting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQAMM.png)

[DP table after sorting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyDpG.png)

Comment: There is no dp in your approach, dp usually refers to usage of past states in order to derive present state.There is no concept of past and present in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution to your problem would be to define the DP state as :-

```
Number of Elements that can be selected from Array1 :- n1

Number of Elements that can be selected from Array2 :- n2

Index of element in new array :- i
```

We know that `n1`+`n2` = `n` = Length of the arrays.

and

`n1`=`n2`=`n/2`

SO in a way, we can say that `n1` and `n2` are related and thus storing only one of them is enough to define a DP state.

DP State :- `(index, number of elements that can be selected from Array1)`

Initial State :- `(0,n/2)`

Transition :- At each index we can either select element from Array1 or Array2 and we want to minimize the cost.

```
f(i,x) = min(Array1[i]+f(i-1,x-1) , Array2[i]+f(i-1,x))
```

This recursion will give you the answer.

Constructing a DP table will solve this problem in O(n^2).